# Github stars not showing correctly in packagist

Tags: php, github, composer-php, packagist, git-webhooks

I have recently created an open source project in github.

https://github.com/sagautam5/local-states-nepal

And then, I have uploaded this package to https://packagist.org,

After that, I have made auto updating by adding web hook. Main problem is star counts are not showing correctly in packagist.

There are 10 stars in the github project but only one star is shown in packagist ? Did I missed something to setup or it's issue in packagist ?

Comment: Why not ask this on https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues?

Comment: @NicoHaase I didn't know about that, Thanks for the info !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *just* published https://packagist.org/packages/sagautam5/local-states-nepal, check if the issue persists in time.

The "[Stars](https://github.com/sagautam5/local-states-nepal/stargazers)" link might have its value cached in the packagist.org page, and maybe in a few hours it will be updated.
Or it was cached at the time of publication (Jan. 4th), and would be updated only if you were to upload a new version today.

Comment: So, I have to release each time to get star counts right ?

Comment: @SagarGautam You can try and release once, today, just to test and see if the stargazers number is updated or not.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I think packagist only updates stars url after each push in github !